# Adding Custom Sticker In PE SDK Android IMG.LY

Tags: sdk

I have added a custom StickerCategoryItem with my PNGs everything is Ok except when I click any sticker, the App crashes with a Null pointer exception. The below error is occurring.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' 
        on a null object reference
        at ly.img.android.pesdk.backend.model.state.manager.StateHandler.createLayerSettingsModel(StateHandler.java:388)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue. I found that I have not declared the sticker assets as the AssetConfig which lead to the crash.

https://img.ly/docs/vesdk/android/features/stickers/#managing-sticker-assets

```
AssetConfig assetConfig = settingsList.getConfig();

assetConfig.addAsset(new ImageStickerAsset("stipop"+spSticker.getStickerId(),ImageSource.create(Uri.parse(spSticker.getStickerImg()))));
ImageStickerItem imageStickerItem = new ImageStickerItem("stipop"+spSticker.getStickerId(), spSticker.getKeyword(), ImageSource.create(Uri.parse(spSticker.getStickerImg()));
```

Update: I was facing a similar issue with the react.js site also. I have added a similar solution for the IMGLY SDK to my react site [Upride](https://upride.in) also and it works fine.